# I need help installing Python on OSX

Tags: python, macos

I'm using the steps on this webpage: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

I'm stuck on this step:  "Once you’ve installed Homebrew, insert the Homebrew directory at the top of your PATH environment variable. You can do this by adding the following line at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file"  I cannot find this file! It's frustrating.

****MY GOAL IS to get pip running on my Mac.****

Comment: So this question is basically "How to install Homebrew on OS X?"

Comment: Essentially Erik. I'm trying to complete the steps on http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Comment: @leon, I'm a beginner at this stuff. Where do I type that in? In Terminal?

Comment: You know OS X comes with Python already, right?

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine, yes I do. However, I'm trying to perfectly understand the steps written on the webpage I provided.

Comment: You can just create `~/.bashrc` if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @Amir, in Terminal (yes): `cd ~`, then `vim .bash_profile` (or use whatever text editor you want and edit your file. You can also use `echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile` as many have mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to install python on OS X. But if you need the most recent version or for some reason there is something wrong with your preinstalled version, python.org offers python-binaries at [this download-page](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/).

If you are new to python, just stick to the preinstalled version. To start the python console, call Terminal and type `python` and `/usr/bin/python` will be called.

If you just want to finish the tutorial, enter the following in Terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After starting a new Tab or restarting Terminal, bash will look for python executable in /usr/local/bin first (the directory used by homebrew) before it searches `/usr/bin/`(The directory for preinstalled stuff for example)

**EDIT**

[For PIP installation guide look here.](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
brew install python
```